# How to send notification from other devices to iOS specific app?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I'm working a feature which will observe the notification from a server and then do some actions. But the notification won't send immediately when I did some changes in the server. So I want to find a way that can send notification or command from other devices or pc to iOS app to test function immediately?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Easy APN Provider](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/easy-apns-provider-push-notification-service-testing-tool/id989622350?mt=12) for testing your push notifications.